# Why I get error: on_load_function_failed,re2

Tags: erlang, phoenix-framework

When I try to start the deployed app, I get this error:

```
initial_call: {supervisor,kernel,['Argument__1']}
    pid: <0.1762.0>
    registered_name: []
    error_info: {exit,{on_load_function_failed,re2},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,352}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
    ancestors: [kernel_sup,<0.1738.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.1739.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 376
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 117
2017-06-19 11:51:18 supervisor_report   
    supervisor: {local,kernel_sup}
    errorContext: start_error
    reason: {on_load_function_failed,re2}
    offender: [{pid,undefined},{id,kernel_safe_sup},{mfargs,{supervisor,start_link,[{local,kernel_safe_sup},kernel,safe]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]
2017-06-19 11:51:19 crash_report        
    initial_call: {application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}
    pid: <0.1737.0>
    registered_name: []
    error_info: {exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,kernel_safe_sup,{on_load_function_failed,re2}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,134}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
    ancestors: [<0.1736.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.1738.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.1736.0>,<0.1735.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 376
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 152
2017-06-19 11:51:19 std_info            
    application: kernel
    exited: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,kernel_safe_sup,{on_load_function_failed,re2}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: permanent
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,kernel_safe_sup,{on_load_function_failed,re2}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,kernel_safe_sup,{on_load_function_failed,re2}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

But I have no idea how to solve this error.. any idea?

**Phoenix app start:**

```
def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      supervisor(MyApp.Endpoint, []),

      # Start the endpoint for schools
      supervisor(MyApp.Schools.Endpoint, []),

      # Start the Ecto repository
      supervisor(MyApp.Schools.Repo, []),
      supervisor(MyApp.Repo, []),

    ]



    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)   
end
```

Comment: Can you show some parts of your code ?

Comment: It's written in elixir, so, I don't know which part causes the error

Comment: Does any of your code have this in it:  `'Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4'` .  A supervisor has children, but all the children have to successfully startup the first time.  I think the error is saying that one or more children failed to startup properly.

Comment: But, how would I know which child has failed?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the start of my app